# Lollipop emulator is unable to start in Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

Here is the list of my emulators in Genymotion:
[image: Devices]

I can start the 2 emulators above (API 17 and 18) normally. But with API 21, whenever I start, I'll get this error:
[image: Error]

Here is my network configuration in Virtual Box:
[image: Adapter]

[image: DHCP]

All Lollipop SDK was installed.

So, what's wrong with the Lollipop emulator? How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @joao2fast4u: any solution yet? :(

Comment: Nope, but there are many related posts in SO

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by opening Genymotion from your desktop access by enabling the execution of administrator.

Verify that you have the latest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this happens to me its a network problem, i just reboot and everything goes ok.

You can try to download the latest version of genymotion if you are running a old one (for me when running lollipop it says that i have an old version and should update).

Comment: I'm using Genymotion 2.5.2. Whatever I do, the problem still remains :(

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Android virtual machine from VirtualBox directly and see if it gives you a more informative error description. For me it was that "amd-v is not enabled".